# Describe the real elements of a Cyclotomic Extension under an Embedding

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

**Set-up**: Let $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ where $\zeta$ is the 5-th root of $1$ and define $\psi:\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)\to\mathbb{C}$, $\zeta^{x}\mapsto1/\zeta^{x}$.

**Aim**: I need to describe the subfield of real elements in $\psi(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta))$ (which I'll label $R$), show that it is a simple extension, and then find the generator.

**My Attempt**:
So far I have that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. I also have that $\psi$ is an injective mapping.

As far as I can work out, $R$ is everything in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ which is mapped to the real line under $\psi$. But isn't it that only $\zeta^{5y}=1$ are mapped to the real line? Clearly, this makes no real sense for the question so I'm guessing not.

To show it is a simple extension I just need to show that it has only one generator - how do I do that?

Comment: Of course, $\zeta$ has complex conjugate $\zeta^4$; so $\zeta+\zeta^4$ is real etc.

Comment: So $\zeta^{x}+\zeta^{4x}\in\mathbb{R}$, so a 'description' of the real elements is just this?

Comment: @GerrySmith  if you want someone to be notified that there is a comment directed at them, start with an "at" sign followed by the first few letters of the user name. The system should show the complete username and allow you to click on that, filling in the entire username, just as happened here for me.  If there are two possible people who share those first few letters, you ought to be given a visible choice.

Comment: @WillJagy, thank you for the information.

Comment: @LordShark... The question above.

Comment: Good. Shark is quite new, he has left some comments for others, but it is not clear he yet checks for comments directed at him; may take him a day or two.

Comment: Oh ok. Well fingers crossed.  Do you happen to know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 2):

You know from Galois theory that there if you call $K$ your cyclotomic extension it is true that $[K: K \cap \mathbb{R}]=[K\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R}]=2$ so that your real subextension has degree $2$ over the rational.(This is a general trick to be sure of the degree of your real subextension). Note also that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$ is a real subextension of $K$ and that it has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. To prove the its degree it's actually $2$ there are lots of ways. Maybe try to prove this.

Comment: Scohnamiglio Would he do this by showing that the minimal polynomial of $zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ is of degree $2$?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Or  you can show that $\zeta$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta +\zeta^{-1})$ by exhibiting its minimum polynomial that is $x^2-(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})x+1$

Comment: Oh, that's good. Thanks to both of you. @TommasoScognamiglio, I like that the minimal polynomial is $x^{2}-(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})x+1$ but how do I show that it is such?

Comment: You know that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta +\zeta^{-1})$ is a real subextension so that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ has degree at least $2$ over it. So if you find a second degree polynomial which has $\zeta$ as one of its roots you are sure that this is its minimum polynomial